# AWS: How to specify a boolean parameter in a CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to specify a boolean parameter in a CloudFormation template so I can conditionally create resources based on a parameter passed in.

Looking at the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-the-new-cloudformation-parameter-types/) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) it would appear there is a discernible lack of a boolean data type.

What is best practice for specifying a boolean? possibly `Number` with 0 or 1 or `String` with `AllowedValues` 'true' and 'false'?

Comment: Why not use a key-pair instead? What's your use case?

Comment: How does key-pair work? The use case is as specified in the question - conditionally creating resources in the template based on an input parameter.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The [Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/) templates are a good, semi-official reference point of how complex templates can/should be created, and they implement Boolean values for Conditional resources exactly as you described, using a `String` with `AllowedValues` `true` and `false`. Here's a specific [example](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-linux-bastion/blob/93b2bc589b398018eb20f6168adfc487a5b5867b/templates/linux-bastion.template#L164-L171):

```
"EnableBanner": {
    "AllowedValues": [
        "true",
        "false"
    ],
    "Default": "false",
    "Description": "To include a banner to be displayed when connecting via SSH to the bastion, set this parameter to true",
    "Type": "String"
}
```

A similar example can be found in the [Conditionally use an existing resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html#d0e164097) example from the CloudFormation documentation, where the `AllowedValues` are `default` or `NONE` (the default).

To conditionally create a resource based on such a boolean parameter, you add a [Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) statement containing a [`Fn::Equals`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-equals) intrinsic function matching `true`, then add a `Condition` key to the resource.

Here's a complete, minimal example template:

[image: Launch Stack]

```
Parameters:
  CreateResource:
    Description: Whether I should create a resource.
    Default: false
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
Conditions:
  ShouldCreateResource:
    !Equals [true, !Ref CreateResource]
Resources:
  Resource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
    Condition: ShouldCreateResource
```

Comment: I'm still unclear as to whether the string `'true'` and the literal `true` evaluate to the same thing. I see examples of both cases in the documentation, seemingly used interchangeably.

Comment: @Arel, in YAML, `'true'` and `true` are both strings.  Quotes around strings are usually optional.  Some exceptions are when numbers or special characters are involved.

Comment: @arel @MarkR the YAML-spec [tag resolution](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) explicitly resolves `true` to a native-boolean type, so `'true'` and `true` do not evaluate to the same thing, at least in YAML itself. In CloudFormation, for String-type Parameter values at least it seems to convert any YAML-native values to String before validating, so in this case at least `'true'` and `true` may be interchangeable for that reason.